# How to transfer data from one csv file to another using SSIS?

Tags: csv, ssis, flatfilesource, flatfiledestination

I have two CSV files. 
Content of first file "c.csv" is :

```
Id,Name
1,Abhishek
2,Abhi
```

and 2nd file "d.csv" is empty.

In SSIS, after creating a package. I am creating a control flow, then data flow. In the data flow, I am importing "flat-file source" followed by creating a 'connection manager' and browsing file "c.csv". After this, I am importing "flat-file source" and using the same 'connection manager' then browsing my empty file 'd.csv'. After executing this, I am getting header transferred and error in "flat-file source" with a red link.

Actually, I am a beginner, I am unable to solve this basic issue. So please provide me an explained solution or any useful resource.

Thank You so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're using "Flat File source" also as a destination? In SSIS sources and destinations are different tasks.

Delete the latter "Flat File Source , drag and drop a "Flat File Destination" task, connect the source task to destination task and configure the destination by setting the destination file and column mappings.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, that was one of the mistake I had done, apart from that, I also had to create separate 'connection manager' for "Flat File Destination".